# Constructing an isomorphism between two rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-isomorphism

Consider a commutative ring $R$ with unity. How does one show that $R$ is isomorphic to the quotient of a polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ (possibly infinitely many variables)?

I have been trying to think of an explicit map, but cannot come up with one. Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any element $r\in R$ and consider

$ \mathbb{Z}[r : r\in R]\to R $

That sends each $r\mapsto r$. The map is defined by linearity and it’s a well defined homomorphism and surjective, so that $R$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[r: r\in R]$

Comment: Thank you for the response. By hook morphism, do you mean monomorphism? Also, I am afraid I don't understand the map completely. Are we sending each $x_i\mapsto r$?

Comment: Never mind, I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: @neophyte yes, I’m sorry I wrote bad